# Return cumulative list from big nested objects in least possible time

Tags: c#, .net

```
Class A
{
   List<B> bObjects;  
}
Class B
{
    List<C> cObjects;
}
Class C
{
     List<D> dOjbects;
}
Class D
{
     List<int> Items;
}
```

What is the best way to traverse List objects and get final list items. Since I am expecting these lists to be big I don't want to traverse through each and every list. What will be efficient way of returning cumulative list of 'ints'.

How to make this small change work?

```
Class A 
{ 
   List<B> bObjects; 
}
Class B 
{
   string Name; 
   List<C> cObjects; 
}
Class C 
{ 
   List<D> dOjbects; 
}
Class D 
{
   List<int> Items; 
}
```

How do I get for every 'Name' cumulative list of Items using Linq

Comment: I don't see any other way, unless you can get at the List<int> Items directly, e.g. by using a targeted stored proc to return all the Items without regard to who owns them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534732%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
listOfAs.SelectMany(a => a.bObjects
        .SelectMany(b => b.cObjects
        .SelectMany(c => c.dObjects
        .SelectMany(d => d.Items))));
```

Comment: If I am not wrong will this not return List<List<int>> instead of one big List<int>

Comment: It will return `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: Thanks for all the help!
Please correct me if I am wrong. Since Items itself is a List and SelectMany returns IEnumerable therefore final output will be more like IEnumerable<List<int>>

Comment: Final output will be `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: Class A
{
   List<B> bObjects;  
}
Class B
{
 string Name;
    List<C> cObjects;
}
Class C
{
     List<D> dOjbects;
}
Class D
{
     List<int> Items;
}

How do I get for every 'Name' cumulative list of Items using Linq

Comment: foreach (var item in listOfAs.SelectMany(a => a.bObjects
                .ToLookup(b => b.Name)
                .Select(bs => new
                {
                    Name = bs.Key,
                    Items = bs
                        .SelectMany(b => b.cObjects
                            .SelectMany(c => c.dObjects
                                .SelectMany(d => d.Items)))
                })))
            {
                string name = item.Name;
                List<int> items = item.Items.ToList();
            }